# Optimization kills the switch statement that I need to use in a function

Tags: stm32, c, optimization, stm32cubeide

Optimization kills the switch statement that I need to use in a function
Hi all, how are you?. I'm doing a project with a STM32F103C6 (it has 32KB flash) and I had to activate optimization options to not run out of memory, right now the optimization options is -Og. After activate optimization a function that I have to know the position of a substring and after that I'm trying to use a switch statement that the compiler is killing and obviously I can't but I don't know why.

Here are de function definitions:

```
void Selec_Opera(char *ent, uint8_t dim)
{
volatile uint8_t pos = 0;
volatile uint8_t lugar = 0;
//  uint8_t com[T_COMANDO] = {0};
pos = strindex(comandos, (char *) eComando);
for(lugar = 0; T_COMANDO*lugar <= pos; lugar++)
{
    asm("nop");
}
switch(lugar)
{
case 0x01:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x02:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x03:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x04:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x05:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 0x06:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
case 7:
{
     lugar++;
}
break;
default:
{
     lugar = 25;
}
break;
}
}


volatile uint8_t strindex(char s[], char t[])
{
uint8_t i, j, k;
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    for (j=i, k=0; t[k]!='\0' && s[j]==t[k]; j++, k++);
    if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
    return i;
}
return -1;
}
```

and I'm calling Selec_Opera() from main like follows:

```
while (1)
{
  if(HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive(&hi2c1, eComando, T_COMANDO, HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK)
  {
      codigoError = 20;
      Error_Handler();
  }
  else
  {
      Selec_Opera((char *) eComando, T_COMANDO);
  }
/* USER CODE END WHILE */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
}
```

The I2C function is working well, the problem is with the function Selec_Opera(). If you wanna know T_COMANDO is defined as 4 and eComando is the array where I'm storing the received stream.

When the Selec_Opera() function is being executed it can be seen that almost all the switch options are not compiled, some pictures can show correctly what I'm tring to explain.

The following image shows that when I'm doing a debug session the debug file has the text but almost all the "switch" options code hasn't been included in the executable file (I need this)

[image: Almost all options killed]

only option 7 and default are included, I've tried only for test with reduced options and the behavior is the same, only the last numbered option and the default option are included in the code (this can be seen because at left is written the memory position of the instruction)

I've tested the "for" statement and it is working well selecting the position where the string is so I don't know what is happening with the switch.

Can anyone help with this?. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you show the assembler code? It most likely got optimized to if(lugar<=7)lugar++;else lugar=25;

Comment: `pos = strindex(comandos, (char *) eComando);` What's `commandos` and `eCommando`? || You do nothing with with the arguments `*ent` and `dim` || After the for loop, `lugar` will always be `pos / 4`. || No need for the switch statement: `lugar = lugar < 8 ? lugar + 1 : 25;` || Lastly, why volatile?

Comment: Your code still works correctly with optimizations turn on, right? Or how does the behavior of the code change?

Comment: Reading again over the code. What does `Selec_Opera` even supposed to do? It's a void function and you only play with variables that are inside the scope of that function.

Comment: Your use of `volatile` disturbs me.

Comment: to @asdfex: Someone explained to me that because the code that like all options are executing exactly the same sentence then the compiler simply joins all numbered options into one and only lets the code of the last option because in that way the switch does exactly the same.

Comment: .to @Swedgin: the function will do several things aftr is finished but I didn't had more progress because of what the optimization was doing.

Comment: to @Codo: The code was working well but not like I expected because I was wrong in my suposition, I didn't knew that the optimization will join every option because the codes inside the options is exactly the same.

Comment: to @Jeroen3: the use of volatile was the only option to avoid the compiler from eliminate those variables since currently I'm not doing anything else with them in the function right now

Comment: @vram Well, you shouldn't be debugging optimized code if you can avoid it. Disable optimizations when you are coding & debugging.

Answer (score 4):

The switch statements gets killed because it gets optimized to `lugar = (lugar > 0) && (lugar < 7) ? lugar + 1 : 25`.

If `lugar` is smaller than 8 and not equal to 0 you always do `+1` otherwise it's equal to `25`. Your code only needs an if statement. Hence only 2 options remain in the optimized code.

Comment: Thanks @Swedgin, that is exactly what was happening

Answer (score 4):

As all cases except default are the same code, the compiler is allowed to reduce that to a single case + default. Why not? There is no need to bloat the result code with the same instuctions several times.

In fact the code is simple

```
if((lugar>0) && (lugar < 8)){
  ++lugar;
}else{
  lugar = 25;      
}
```

and that is exactly what the compiler will generate I guess

Comment: Thanks @schnedan, that is exactly what was happening

Comment: @Swedgin correct me if I am wrong, but the original code does not count +1 if lugar is 0 but executes the default case...

Comment: @schnedan yes you are right. I overlooked that fact.

Comment: actually where the lugar++ are is going to be a different function for each case but I've put it that way for lack of experience.

Comment: @vram oh, so that is placeholder code.  It’s optimizing it lol...

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` access isn't allowed to be optimized, but the compiler can optimize the surrounding code. Your code reads `lugar` once and then writes to it once. Those two accesses are not allowed to be optimized out. This means that the code may get optimized into something similar to this:

```
tmp = lugar;
if(tmp>0 && tmp < 8)
  tmp++;
else 
  tmp = 25;
lugar = tmp;
```

The important part here is that the number of side effects (read/writes on the `volatile` variable) stay the same and aren't re-ordered.

`volatile` aside, `switch` statements are almost always optimized into something more efficient - don't expect to be able to single step through them in optimized C code. When there are no `volatile` around, they often get replaced by function pointer lookup tables.